# Expertise regarding [gosu] and [libgosu]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

In working on a game project in Ruby, I've been trying to look for bits of information via the [gosu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gosu) tag, which I believed corresponded to the C++/Ruby game development library, [libgosu](https://www.libgosu.org/).

However, it turns out there's a relatively-new (ie. 5 years old) programming language for the JVM also called [Gosu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosu_(programming_language)).

The tag wikis and descriptions for each of these, [libgosu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libgosu) and [gosu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gosu) respectively, appear to have been updated, but there are a lot of questions out there which require tag edits to be correct.

I've gone through and cleaned up any [gosu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gosu) questions which refer to libgosu, but my edits are pending review.

What else, if anything, should be done to resolve this, and what should I do to try and prevent this confusion in the future?

Comment: Well, one *could* think about abolishing the tag gosu in favor of libgosu (exists) and gosu-lang (in the spirit of crystal-lang factor-lang figaro-lang julia-lang logo-lang q-lang shakespeare-lang slim-lang snap-lang turing-lang), if gosu is esoteric enough to avoid mis-tagging.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, either. The Gosu language does seem to be quite rare, despite its merits. I don't think anyone would mind terribly.

Comment: Can you quickly check the remaining questions in the [gosu] tag to make sure that they all refer to the gosu language? I can then rename the tag to [gosu-lang] as suggested.